# Social Network (Facebook, Twitter, etc) User Account Integration (duplicate scenario)

Tags: facebook, twitter, user-accounts, account-management

So there are definitely many tutorials out there regarding how to integrate various individual social network authentication/registration into existing user accounts.  But the scenario I can't seem to find out much information about is if a user signs into your account with different social network credentials.  For example:

**Scenario #1**
*User registers on site using site's authentication.*
*User then signs in/registers on site using Facebook Connect.*
*User then signs in/registers on site using Twitter.*

How do I integrate all of these into one account?

Obviously once a user is registered, they can add other social network associations in the account settings pages.  But I am more concerned if they register via the other social network not remembering they are already setup.

My general thoughts are trying to figure out a way to use the "username" or email to try and guess and present the user a way to combine accounts right there.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

following up -

if your users can't remember that they've signed up previously, well, best of luck to them in general ;)

much as you described, i'm planning on giving users the option to link additional accounts once they have signed in by one means or another.

but as far as cross-checking, there's only so much you can do.  many social network APIs do indeed provide email addresses (once you've busted in through OAuth) but these may be accessible only if a user has elected to make his/her address public, which is not guaranteed.

also not guaranteed is that the user used the SAME email address for each social network account, so even if you manage to retrieve an address it may or not be of any use to you.

finally, if you find matching email addresses via such means, it might be advisable to prompt the user to link accounts rather than assume he/she wants this done automatically.  some people like to maintain multiple personalities.  i.e. "it looks like you are also signed up with twitter - do you want to link your accounts?  it will make your life seem worth living."

you might consider offering incentives to link user accounts or to provide an email address (up to you of course to figure out what these might be, based on the functionality of your website).

solution i am working on, database-side, is to maintain multiple accounts and then if link information is discovered by various means, said link is indicated in a lookup table.
an alternative is once you find a link, attempt to combine all relevant entries for the multiple accounts into one account entity - all i can say about this latter approach is that i would do so with caution as there could be a formidable level of complexity depending on the user's activity level and the complexity of your database schema.

in my (mental/actual) namespace a user who registers the old-fashioned way has a 'standard' account and one who uses a social network has an 'alias' account.  then the goal becomes to define where the alias is supposed to point, i.e. create the lookup such that a subsequent login via *either* means retrieves the relevant information for *both* accounts (with a preference for displaying personal data for the 'standard' account).

btw i figured out how to make twitter OAuth behave since my last post - you can look at my other answers for details if you're interested.

JB

> hi matt,
>
> i'm working on the same problem right
>   now.
>
> assuming the user starts with regular
>   site account (which is *not*
>   necessarily safe to assume if he sees
>   all the pretty "connect with XXX
>   network" buttons!!!), you can use
>   either OAuth or the javascript APIs
>   (facebookConnect or @anywhere -
>   haven't fully figured out the latter
>   yet and i'm not sure I recommend it as
>   I don't think it provides as rich an
>   API as do the backend libraries) to
>   login to the other sites.
>
> the APIs should return certain
>   information after a successful
>   login/redirect from the social network
>   - such as the user ID and an ACCESS TOKEN which you can then store in your
>   database in some capacity associating
>   your 'actual' application user with
>   the ID of the social network.
>
> when the user returns to the site, you
>   can then
>
> 1 verify cookies set by the social
>   network services (various schemes
>   typically verifying a signature, based
>   on sha1 or md5 hash of your
>   application data - by which i mean the
>   data you get when you register your
>   app with twitter/facebook, typically a
>   consumer key, application ID, etc. -
>   with the received cookies) so you know
>   the user has logged in with the social
>   network
>
> 2 find your database entry association
>   as described above
>
> 3 login your user *manually* based on
>   the assumption that facebook/twitter
>   connection is secure.
>
> caveat: this is only as secure as your
>   implementation (or as secure as
>   facebook/twitter's implementations, if
>   you prefer...)
>
> although twitter's OAuth does not
>   currently seem to work quite right,
>   their general description of the
>   process is pretty informative:
>   http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth
>
> good luck.
>
> J

Comment: j,

glad to see someone else working on this issue.

i feel i get the scenario you described, where the user first registers a site account, and then wants to attach other social network accounts, etc.

my main issue is grasping the other scenario, when the user first uses the "sign-in with XXX" buttons, without having a site account.  obviously i need to automatically generate an account, but what happens when they come back to the site, and use a different "sign-in with XXX" button?  should i check based on email?  what should i display to the user?

matt

Comment: it's tough to find a foolproof plan.  one thing - not really a programmatical so much as a UX solution - i've seen sites do is have a profile page (and occasionally PROMPT the user in some way to 'complete your profile') where one can enter additional or 'link to' social network settings.  once you have this data you can draw the logical conclusions server-side and create the appropriate links in your user DB.

Answer (score 1):

I have been contemplating adding FB auth to our app, but we know that our returning users might click it and complete checkout for a new item, and then be surprised to not see any of their existing orders. To solve this, when a user clicks the 'Login with Facebook' item, we are using that click to fire a dropdown menu with two options:

[image: mockup]

[ Login with Facebook ] 
[ Create new account  ] 
[  I have an account  ]

If the user clicks 'I have an account' we send them to FB auth and return email from FB to our app. We compare that email to our existing users. If we match, we add the FB creds to the user. If no match, we throw an alert:

> The email you have with FB does not match any of our accounts. To log in to your existing account, login with your email below, or update the email in your Facebook account

This allows the user to create a whole new account, if they want to keep them separate, without needing a new email service. While this is an edge case, it is a feature.